# How can I merge a remote branch into a local one that has one commit ahead?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull

I have two machines a PC and a laptop. I was working on a project that was up to date in the laptop, in the PC and in the remote repository. Suddenly while I was in the laptop, I realized that one commit that I had done in main should be in another branch so I did a `git reset --soft` to the previous commit, created the new branch with `git checkout -b` and commited the changes to it.
After that I wanted to push the changes and I had to do a `git push --force`. Then I came to the PC, did a `git fetch`, created a new local branch to make changes to the new remote branch with `git branch <branch name> <base branch>`, but when I want to merge origin/main into main, git gives me `Already up to date`.

I've tried adding `-f` and `--force` but it is not working. Of course I could do a reset `--hard` but I wanted to know if there is another way. I expect to have the same version of the remote repository in local.

Comment: To clarify, "After that I wanted to push the changes and I had to do a `git push --force`". Do you mean that one commit was already everywhere on `main`, and you had to force push `main` to remove that 1 commit?

Comment: Yes actually I had 3 commits, but I reset the last one, and I used `push --force` to erase it from the remote repository.

Comment: "I expect to have the same version of the remote repository in local" Clone the remote and that's exactly what you'll have. But that is also what `git fetch` does.

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. Let's start by studying the situation. Say `git fetch; git switch main; git status`. Report back to us.

Comment: As far as git in concerned, your local main is ahead of git/main, so merging does nothing.   If main was not your working branch, you could do `git fetch origin +main:main`, but if it is you working branch, you'll need a reset.

Comment: Finally a did a reset. That was my original idea, I only want to know if there are any other way. Thanks